# Extract viewState with Scala regex

Tags: regex, scala

I have a hard time extracting data from the following string

```
="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[4685053375524352423:5595878640051746918]
```

I want the data inside CDATA[-HERE-]

So far I try :

```
  val jsjPostViewStateCheck = regex("""="javax.faces.ViewState"><!\[CDATA\[([^\]]*)""")
    .saveAs("viewState")
```

It is not working. Is there a tool for scala regex checking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems to be fine, you can test it **[here](https://regex101.com/r/jE1pC4/1)**:

You have to grab the capturing group content. Try this code:

```
val string = "javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[4685053375524352423:5595878640051746918]"
val pattern = """="javax.faces.ViewState"><!\[CDATA\[([^\]]*)""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
   m => println(m.group(1))
}
```

Comment: I was overwhelmed. Thanks I just realized that it was working.